# DO I need to have Airport transit visa if my US F1 visa is expired and I have H1b approval notice?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, f1-visas, h1b-visas

My F1 visa expired in June 2018. My OPT is valid till Jan 30, 2019. I got my H1b approved this year, so officially from Oct 1st, 2018 I am on H1 now and I have H1b approval notice. I am travelling from the USA to India (where I will be going for H1b stamping) from 17th November to 10th Dec 2018 through Lufthansa and have 4 hr layover in Frankfurt, Germany. Would I need Airport transit visa? I am an Indian citizen.

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange! I assume from your question that you are an Indian citizen?

Comment: Also, will you be travelling to India directly from the USA?

Comment: Yes and yes....

Answer (score 1):

According to [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx), the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Nationals of India transiting through Frankfurt (FRA) or Munich (MUC),
> arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward
> ticket for a flight within 24 hours to a third country which is not a
> Schengen Member State. They must:
>
> - have a used, valid or expired visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or United
>   Kingdom, and
> - be returning from the country that issued the visa, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for their next destination.

So if you hold an Indian passport and are travelling *directly* (as I read your question) from the United States to Frankfurt and then on to India with a four-hour connection, then it appears that you do not need a visa.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Appreciate it.

Comment: @ArpitPatel if you'll forgive me, local etiquette is that you accept an answer you're happy with by clicking the "tick" outline next to it.  This puts the question to bed and stops it floating around forever like a querulous albatross.  It also drives the local reputation system, both for you and the author of the answer you accept.  My apologies if you already know this.

Comment: I would just ask you to check with the airline to confirm. A friend of mine had the exact same situation as yours and was denied boarding from Seattle on Virgin Atlantic. Though I understand LHR and Virgin Atlantic are different from FRA and Lufthansa, just check to be sure. My friend had to rebook on Emirates.

Comment: @BhushanKale No, that is a different situation. The UK has completely different rules to Schengen.

Comment: I agree, though, that it never hurts to call the airline to confirm, especially in a somewhat-complicated situation like this.